# Is there any way to solve "string index out of range"

Tags: python

My problem is to count words having alphabet 'a' at second position in a string
Eg : banana in a bag
o/p banana bag

```
for i in re:
    if i[1]== 'a':
        print(i)
```

It was showing index out of range error due to word "a" in a sentence
I want output without error can anyone solve it?

Comment: Either catch the exception or test whether your string is longer than 1 first…?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted If i am clear..!
**Please let me know.!!**

**Code:-**

```
string="banana in a bag"
result=""
for word in string.split():
    try: 
        if word[1]=="a":
            result+=word+" "
    except IndexError:
        continue
print(result)
```

**Output:-**

```
banana bag
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use EAFP pattern here

```
try
  index = 1 # for example
  my_str = '';
  print(my_str[index])
except IndexError:
  # handle your error here.
```